# How does three.js handle rotations by non-unit quaternions?

Tags: three.js, quaternions

With three.js, I use a quaternion to rotate an arrow (located on the unit sphere).

I have a complete script in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/PhilipZhu/937wov02/1/

Most of the codes are for setups. The relavant parts are typed below:

```
// define a quaternion

let u = -0.3; // scaling factor of non-unit quaternion
let t = 0.25*Math.PI; // rotate by angle 2*t

let w = Math.exp(u)*Math.cos(t);
let x = Math.exp(u)*Math.sin(t);
let y = 0;
let z = 0;

let q = { w: w, x: x, y: y, z: z };
```

The above code sets up a quaternion that rotates around x-axis by `2*t`, and the quaternion is scaled by `exp(u)`. That means when `u=0`, q is a unit quaternion.

```
// define an arrow shape
const points = [];
points.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0    , 1 ,  0     ) );
...
points.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0    , 1 ,  0     ) );
```

These points traces an arrow shape located on the unit sphere.

```
// Method 1: apply quaternion to Vector3 (blue)
let transformedPoints = points.map((point) => {
  return point.clone().applyQuaternion(quaternion);
});
const arrowMaterial1 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
const geometry1 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( transformedPoints );
const arrow1 = new THREE.Line( geometry1, arrowMaterial1 );
arrow1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(arrow1);

// Method 2: apply quaternion to Object3 (green)
const arrowMaterial2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const arrow2 = new THREE.Line( geometry2, arrowMaterial2 );
arrow2.position.set(0, 0, 0);
arrow2.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion);
scene.add(arrow2);
```

My main question is, the above method 1 and method 2 gives to different shapes when q is non-unitary.

Method 1 copies geometry data to (three.js) Vector3 objects and then apply the quaternion to Vector3, and this method gives intuitive outcome: rotated by expected angle and scaled with respect to the origin.

Method 2 sets a (three.js) Object3 object and then apply the quaternion to Ojbect3. This gives an unintuitive outcome that is different than what method 1 gives.

What is the reason (if there is any) behind it? or is it a bug that no one cares since non-unit quaternion transformation is not common at all?

Comment: With some experients I found that for Object3D, if a a zero quaternion is applied (x,y,z,w)=(0,0,0,0), then the object is not rotated, while I was expecting that a quaternion multiplication of (0,0,0,0) would make everything shink to the origin

Comment: I asked the same question on threejs's forum, and this thread seems to explain what's happening https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-does-three-js-handle-rotations-by-non-unit-quaternions/52272/10